# Magento2 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: e-commerce, magento2, http-status-code-504

I'm dev my e-commerce with Magento 2, hosted on Siteground shared server.
Since my db is getting bigger, I suppose the server takes too much time to respond, so I get 504 Gateway Timeout (if I try to add/edit products). I read I should edit some php timeout params, but I can't on a shared service. So now, is that any solution?

**SOLUTION**
I just had to migrate to a dedicated Cloud, Magento is a really huge monster!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have updated the php  version on siteground hosting,
by default it will be 5.6, so try to use 7.0, and then refresh your browser,cache etc, it should work fine.